# iOS Broadcast Extension(Screen Broadcasting) is not Working

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, ios-app-group, replaykit

I'm new to Programming Business and making Broadcasting App Which is supposed to Handle Screen Broadcast Function(iPhone Control Center --> Broadcast. Like a Mobcrush).

So I try to implement Broadcast App Extension that was introduced at WWDC, but my Demo App Doesn't work well. My Demo App Just Doesn't Broadcast And Just Show Me an Error Alert Which Says "Live Broadcast to MYDemoApp has stopped due to: (null)"

**Here Are The Things What I Did On Demo App**

1. Implementing App Extension(BroadCast Extension. Which Makes SampleHandler, BroadcastSetupViewController)
2. Implementing App Group(Setting Capability, BundleIdentifier, 
   Setting App Groups And Provisioning Profile in Developer.Apple.com)
3. Pod Install And Copied The Codes That I Didn't Write From Other Developer's Demo App (HaishinKit)
   (https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift)
4. Put RTMP URL String in userDidFinishSetup() in BroadcastSetupViewController 
   (This App is Demo, So i Just Put My Own RTMP Address And Stream Key. Like This : rtmp://bc.CompanyName.tv/app/VeryLongStreamKey)

Plus, I Think this is Not an RTMP URL Issue. because I already did Camera(Front, Rear) Broadcast Test With That URL(Not an App Extension. Just in the Simple ViewController).

Could you Tell Me A Hint? Any Feedback Would Be Appreciated!

Thank For You Reading My First Question About Coding.

[This is an Alert That I Saw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsieR.png)

Comment: The alert seems to come up a lot.  It happens for me whenever the app runs out of memory.

Comment: I Checked Debug Navigator After I Read Your Reply. And I Saw My Demo App Consumes 15MB Memory.

Comment: It not just happen for that, sometimes for any other unexpected stop

Comment: Hey @JunYoungJee I am trying the same feature but i am getting [ERROR] Failed to determine whether URL /broadcast (n) is managed by a file provider error what ever url i use as a broad cast url. Any idea what was wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

I found there is many limitations on iOS broadcast extension.
- If extension started by container app via API, Network become off when app goes background.
- File access is not possible.
- Asset access is not possible.
- Swift print() do nothing. Use NSLog() and idevicesyslog.
- Xcode "Attach to process by PID or Name..."  works.

If you get "due to (null)" error, debug on Xcode by attaching process.
Or put NSLog() and see by idevicesyslog.